# How to restore ownership/permissions for a folder on a networked drive

Tags: windows, permissions, nas

We have multiple systems (running from Windows Vista to 10) and keep all of our data on a NAS drive.  One subfolder has lost all permissions & ownership.  Have tried takeown, but appear to not know correct formatting of command for a networked drive.  Have tried changing permissions of parent folder & all child folders, get error msg:  Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied

This folder has crucial data in it that must be recovered.  What other steps can I take?

Comment: Try mapping Drive (`net use Z: \\server\share`) then run the commands that way? What filesystem is the NAS using?

Comment: Filesystem/drive failing? Does the NAS show any errors, or can it do any (readonly?) filesystem checks / fsck / chkdsk, or allow ddrescue / dd recovery?